# Matplotlib & Excel: How to evenly slice the x-axis of a plot?

Tags: python, excel, matplotlib, plot

I have a bunch of particular datasets that come from a set of `n` simulations. All my datasets look like the following excerpt, and are all saved in an `xlsx` file:

```
           SET1   SET2   SET3  ...   SET n
PHASE A    945    911    847   ...   ...
PHASE B    17     12     86    ...   ...
```

Using `matplotlib` and `Excel`, I would like to produce a plot that is visually like this (made-up example), where the x-axis is evenly sliced:
[image]

To give you more details, these are the properties of such a plot:

1. For each set, the values have `1000` as upper boundary and `0` as lower boundary;
2. The values always decrease from `1000` to a smaller value and there is continuity where the red and blue curve meet;
3. The origin does not correspond to `0` along the `x-axis`, but to `1000`;
4. Each vertical tick corresponds to `0` for the set to its left and to `1000` for the set to its right;
5. `Phase A` and `Phase B` do not represent any value - they are `categories`;
6. The value `(SET1, Phase A)` equals `1000-945`, while `(SET1, Phase B)` equals `1000-945-17`.

**My question:** How could such plot be produced in `matplotlib` or even `Excel`? I am sorry not to be able to provide any `Python` code as I have absolutely no idea of how such a plot could be structured. Apologies and thanks to anyone who will be patient enough to help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are asking too much.
On [matplotlib.org](http://matplotlib.org/) are many examples and all the documentation you could need.
Here is a minimal example that has at least a few of the features:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 400)
y = np.sin(x ** 2)

f, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, sharey=True)
ax1.plot(x, y)
ax1.set_title('Sharing Y axis')
ax2.scatter(x, y)
f.gca().invert_xaxis() 
f.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.0)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks. Anyway, the fact that the plot itself may be hard to explain does not entail that I am asking too much. This is not a software service but if I knew how to do it I would have never posted this question.